# Why building angular forms with formcontrol.values not setting the validations

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I needed to create form in this way. app.ts file ->

> courseNameControl =  new FormControl("",
> [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)]);
>
> contentControl = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
>
> form = {   coursename: this.courseNameControl.value,   content:
> this.contentControl.value, } testForm=this.fb.group(this.form)

This form does not create the validations properly. Does anyone have a clue why?

Comment: I suppose cause your `form` property is simple object with properties `coursename` and `content`. but you should pass `FormControl` instances to `this.fb.group`

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't NEED to do it this way.

Just do it properly.

```js
testForm = this.fb.group({
  coursename: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
  content: ['', [Validators.required]]
});
```

But to answer your question, your `form` value is

```js
{ coursename: '', content: '' }
```

Do you see any validators in that ?